# How to setup Custom RMI client socket factory for remote JMX connection?

Tags: ssl, rmi, jmx

I am working on a prototype application for fetching data from multiple secure JMX servers. I am using custom ssl rmi factory which creates socket with appropriate truststore and keystore. However, it is not invoked by JMX connector stub.

Instead I get this error in client application

```
java.rmi.ConnectIOException: non-JRMP server at remote endpoint
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:248)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:202)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:130)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIServerImpl_Stub.newClient(Unknown Source)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.getConnection(RMIConnector.java:2404)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.connect(RMIConnector.java:308)
    at javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory.connect(JMXConnectorFactory.java:270)
    at Client.main(Client.java:86)
```

**Server**

```
HashMap env = new HashMap();   
SslRMIServerSocketFactory ssf = new SslRMIServerSocketFactory();
env.put(RMIConnectorServer.RMI_SERVER_SOCKET_FACTORY_ATTRIBUTE,ssf);

JMXServiceURL url = new JMXServiceURL( "service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:9999/server");
JMXConnectorServer cs =  JMXConnectorServerFactory.newJMXConnectorServer(url, env, mbs);

System.out.println("\nStart the RMI connector server");
cs.start();
```

**Client**

```
HashMap env = new HashMap();        
SslRMIClientSocketFactory csf1 = new CustomSslRMIClientSocketFactory();
RMIClientSocketFactory csf2 = RMISocketFactory.getDefaultSocketFactory();

env.put(RMIConnectorServer.RMI_CLIENT_SOCKET_FACTORY_ATTRIBUTE, csf1);
env.put("com.sun.jndi.rmi.factory.socket", csf2);        

JMXServiceURL url =  new JMXServiceURL("service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://:9999/server");
JMXConnector jmxc = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(url, env);

System.out.println("connection id " + jmxc.getConnectionId());
```

**Steps to run prototype application**

- start rmiregistry (insecure) on port 9999
- java -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=config/keystore -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=password  Server
- java Client